# How can a user run Selenium-TestNG-Maven project in Jenkins with multiple browsers

Tags: maven, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I am running Selenium-TestNG-Maven project in Jenkins. I am able to run the tests in single browsers, that is through Chrome or Firefox or IE. But if the user want to run in multiple browsers through Jenkins UI, how can i achive it? My current Jenkins UI is given below

[image]

the command used for running the test is

```
mvn test -Durl=https://xxxxxx.com -Dbrowser=chrome -DsuiteXmlFile=loginTestng.xml
```

my pom.xml file is given below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>MockTest</groupId>
<artifactId>MockFrameTest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>6.14.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28</version>
  </dependency>   
  <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies> 

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <baseUrl>${url}</baseUrl>
                    <browserName>${browser}</browserName>   
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <suiteXmlFiles> 
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile> 
                </suiteXmlFiles> 

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

my tesng.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
 <suite name="Suite" >
  <test name="Test1">
   <classes>
    <class name="testPackage.testngdemo"/>
   </classes>
  </test>   
 </suite>
```

and code i ahve written for driver intialization in the java class is

```
if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {                   
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }       
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {            
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();}
```

So if i give multiple browsernames in 'mvn test -Durl=https://xxxxxx.com -Dbrowser=chrome,firefox -DsuiteXmlFile=loginTestng.xml ',how will be the changes in pom file and testng.xml file.
So that user can enter chrome in Jenkins UI for running in a single browser and the user can  enter 'chrome,firefox' in Jenkins UI for running in multiple browsers.an anyone help to achive this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: I strongly recommend to take a deep look into https://testcontainers.org which offers such things via docker container....

Comment: @khmarbaise, Thanks for the reply...So we can't implement this using Jenkins?